# Is there any way to make common function out of these two blocks

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, refactoring

I have two blocks; in each block, I am retrieving the data from a table using command and reader and transforming the data, and then updating the same. What I am looking to extract the common function by passing the table name, type, and transform function to that function from these two blocks

Below is the code for the same,

// Block #1

```
using var queryProjectSteamSystemsCommand = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
queryProjectSteamSystemsCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT ""Id""::varchar, ""InitialObject""::varchar from ""DesignHubProjectSteamSystems""";
using var steamSystemProjectsReader = queryProjectSteamSystemsCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (steamSystemProjectsReader.HasRows)
{
    while (steamSystemProjectsReader.Read())
    {
        var id = steamSystemProjectsReader.IsDBNull(0) ? Guid.Empty : Guid.Parse(steamSystemProjectsReader.GetString(0));
        var steamSystemJson = steamSystemProjectsReader.IsDBNull(1) ? "null" : steamSystemProjectsReader.GetString(1);
        var projSteamSystemInitialObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OldSteamSystem>(steamSystemJson);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TransformProjectSteamSystem(projSteamSystemInitialObj)).Replace("'", "''", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        migrationBuilder.Sql($"UPDATE \"DesignHubProjectSteamSystems\"  SET \"InitialObject\" = '{json}'::jsonb WHERE \"Id\" = '{id}'");
    }
}
steamSystemProjectsReader.Close();
```

// Block #2

```
using var queryProjectFuelSystemsCommand = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
queryProjectFuelSystemsCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT ""Id""::varchar, ""InitialObject""::varchar from ""DesignHubProjectFuelSystems""";
using var fuelSystemProjectsReader = queryProjectFuelSystemsCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (fuelSystemProjectsReader.HasRows)
{
    while (fuelSystemProjectsReader.Read())
    {
        var id = fuelSystemProjectsReader.IsDBNull(0) ? Guid.Empty : Guid.Parse(fuelSystemProjectsReader.GetString(0));
        var fuelSystemJson = fuelSystemProjectsReader.IsDBNull(1) ? "null" : fuelSystemProjectsReader.GetString(1);
        var projFuelSystemInitialObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OldFuelSystem>(fuelSystemJson);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TransformProjectFuelSystem(projFuelSystemInitialObj)).Replace("'", "''", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        migrationBuilder.Sql($"UPDATE \"DesignHubProjectFuelSystems\"  SET \"InitialObject\" = '{json}'::jsonb WHERE \"Id\" = '{id}'");
    }
}
fuelSystemProjectsReader.Close();
```

I cannot combine `OldSteamSystem` and `OldFuelSystem` two classes, which are different. I can't make any familiar interface and abstract class out of these two.

So, could anyone please let me know how to make a common function out of it?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you use Generics?

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: If I want to use generics, there must be a connection between the two types, but I cannot make that.

Comment: That is not true. You don't need a generic constraint to use generics.

Comment: That's what I am looking to get, but I did not get any idea about this.

Comment: Other than variable names changing from "fuel" to "steam", is there any difference in any of the lines between the two blocks besides the generic argument passed to `DeserializeObject`? Do you have any logic different depending on which type you use?

Comment: and I do have two different actions as well, `TransformProjectFuelSystem` and `TransformProjectSteamSystem`

Comment: three differences are there one is the table name, generic argument, and method where it transforms the data

Comment: What do those two methods take and return?

Comment: they take one form of object and modify and return the modified object back

Comment: Here I think I need to have two generic arguments if function as parameter passing to that common method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics, and ask for the table name and a method to transform the object.

```
void DoTheThing<TSystem>(string tableName, Func<TSystem, TSystem> transform)
{
    using var command = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = @$"SELECT ""Id""::varchar, ""InitialObject""::varchar from ""{tableName}""";
    // I know I complain about SQL injection, you get to fix this one...

    using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var id = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? Guid.Empty : Guid.Parse(reader.GetString(0));
            var initialJson = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? "null" : reader.GetString(1);
            var initialObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TSystem>(initialJson);
            
            // this uses the "transform" parameter, IE a method your caller provides
            string transformedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transform(initialObj)).Replace("'", "''", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            migrationBuilder.Sql($"UPDATE \"{tableName}\"  SET \"InitialObject\" = '{transformedJson}'::jsonb WHERE \"Id\" = '{id}'");
            // again, SQL injection
        }
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

If the `transform` method takes one type and returns a *different* type, then change the method signature to

```
void DoTheThing<TSystem, TTransformed>(string tableName, Func<TSystem, TTransformed> transform)
```

Comment: Also, Can you please point me to where the usage of generics is listed without type constraint

Comment: "Without type constraints" just means you don't have a `where` clause. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Comment: Just a quick question on the above scenario, I want to pass TSystem and TTransformed as a list of objects everywhere. Instead of this `TSystem` inside the method, I would like to use List<Tsystem> and it looks like I am  getting an error

Comment: I would like to pass `void DoTheThing<List<TSystem>, List<TTransformed>>(string tableName, Func<List<TSystem>, List<TTransformed>> transform)`

Comment: with the above getting a syntax error at here `TransformSystemsList<List<TOldSystem>, List<TNewSystem>>`

Comment: Could you please let me know is there any way to achieve the same

Comment: Take out `List` from the generic argument list. The name you specify in the generic arguments list is the _name_ of the type argument. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics If you need more help, please post a new question.

Comment: Thanks again, Sure, I believe the existing example is working as expected, and below is How I am passing to that method for the list `MigrationHelper.TransformSystems<List<OldAirDistribution>, List<NewAirDistribution>>("AirSystems", Utils.TransformAirDistribution, migrationBuilder, dbContext, "Distributions");`

Comment: we can pass anything in place of `TSystem` either list or the other